# Detect and return language for each tweet in a list of tweets

Tags: python, textblob

I'm trying to detect and return the language of each tweet in a list of tweets. I'm using textblob's detect_language function.

I guess that I'd need to use a for loop to iterate over each tweet in the list. But I'm stuck on how to do this. Do I need to use a TextBlob object in the loop, or something else?

```
from textblob import TextBlob
df = pd.read_csv("christian_sex_tweets.csv")
text = df["Message"]

# join all tweets into a big text
text = " ".join(review for review in df["Message"])
print ("There are {} words in the combination of all review.".format(len(text)))

sex_tweets_blob = TextBlob(text)

# detect languages in tweets 
tweets_langs = sex_tweets_blob.detect_language()

for lang in tweets_langs: 
    print(lang)

e
s
```

It just returns "e s". Can anyone help me fix the loop so it returns a list of languages for each tweet?

Thanks

Comment: you're missing a `:` at the end of the `for` loop

Comment: The loop works now, but it only returns "e s" for Spanish. How would I make it return a list of languages for each tweet?